# How do you link a number to text in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a controlled assessment at school, and one of the tasks is that you should have prices for different qualities of pet food and bedding.

I have tried using `insert spinner` in `Developer`, but it only works for number value, and I need high, low, and medium qualities of pet food and bedding.

Here is a screenshot of the animal table:

[image: Right here]

Comment: Take a looke at Vlookup.  build a table with your look up on the left and the value on the right.  Alternatively you can use an INDEX/MATCH combination.

Comment: @ForwardEd OK, will get back to you!

Comment: Or, use Number Formatting, such as `[=3]"High";[=2]"Medium";[=1]"Low"` so that the numbers 1, 2 and 3 *display* as "Low", "Medium" and "High".

Comment: `=INDEX({"High","Med","Low"},1,A1)` where A1 would be the spinner value for example.